# PFQueryTableViewController refresh data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

Until now i refreshet the data when the user would navigate from another ViewController to my `PFQueryTableViewController` like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //self.loadObjects()
}
```

The new version of ParseUI removed `self.loadObjects()`. 
How do i tell the my `PFQueryTableViewController` to refresh the data without using "Pull to refresh"?

Comment: You can still use it but you have to put the .loadObjects() on the PFQueryTableViewController so: PFQueryTableViewController.loadObjects(self). Something like that with your own references should work.

Comment: Hey, it did not work. There isn't any method called loadObjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/issues/99) fixed it. I forgot to import `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>` to my bridging header.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, even if the OP is the one answering it. I experienced the same problem. I really wish Parse would update their libraries to not have to use the bridging headers.